# why RequiredFieldValidator control does not work after adding OnClientClick event for submit button?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, web-controls

I use .net RequiredFieldValidator control for those required fields validation, but I also need to verify fields using regular expression,and some other logic, so I also added OnClientClick event function to the submit button. But I found after adding the OnClientClick event, all requiredfieldvalidator validation events are not fired after clicking submit button. Why? if it is the mechanism, how can I use both of them?

Comment: Did you add it programatically with = or +=?

Comment: it's like OnClientClick="return CheckForm();"

Answer (score 0):

I've run into the same problem in the past. I haven't dug into the why, but I've called the `Page_ClientValidate('ValidationGroup')` javascript function directly in my OnClientClick event.

For example:

```
OnClientClick="if(Page_ClientValidate('Zip')) DoSomething();"
```